# how to sort alphabetically in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have this code where I do `.each_slice(2)` and then I want to `sort` alphabetically but just adding sort after doesn't work also `to_a.sort` doesn't work either:

```
.form-group__container
  .form-group__row
    - Algorithm.where(filterable: 'true').each_slice(2).sort do |algorithms|
      .form-group__col
        - algorithms.each do |algorithm|
```

Can anybody show me how is it done in ruby on rails?

Comment: `each_slice(2)` creates subarrays of size 2. are you trying to sort these subarrays? if so, what are you trying to sort by?

Comment: @dimanyc I am trying to sort for example a list for ex.  ["google", "bing", "msn", "apple", "microsoft"]

Comment: `Algorithm.where(filterable: 'true').each_slice(2)` returns an Enumerator obj that would look like this:
`[[#<Algorithm id: 1, name: "mergesort"], #<Algorithm id: 2, name: "dijkstra"], [..and so on]]`. If you want to sort the subarrays by, say, the `name` attr, in the last line, instead of `algorithms.each do |algo|`, you can do `algorithms.sort_by(&:name) do |algo|`

Comment: I get a syntax error `both block arg and actual block given`

Comment: whoops. typo. Do this: `algorithms.sort_by(&:name).each do |algo|`

Comment: exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: np! one last thing I noticed. Remove `.sort` from `Algorithm.where(filterable: 'true').each_slice(2).sort do |algorithms|` leave it as `Algorithm.where(filterable: 'true').each_slice(2) do |algorithms|`

Comment: @dimanyc yes I already did that. But I just noticed that it doesn't sort all the algorithms in ascending order somehow, it orders b and then c and then b again sometimes? Any idea why it could be so?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208889/discussion-between-dimanyc-and-gty1996).

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. We need to be able to duplicate the problem however your example code isn't sufficient to let us do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help from @dimanyc the solution to my problem looks like this:

```
- Algorithm.where(filterable: 'true').sort_by(&:name).each_slice(2) do |algorithms|
```